# JavaScript error thrown by adzerk script in many page loads

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

On roughly 50% of page loads on stackoverflow.com, with the developer tools open in Chrome (44.0.2403.157 m), I'm seeing an error being reported:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse
    JSON.parse @ ados.js:3
    impressionData @ ados.js:443
    root.ados_writePixel @ ados.js:753
    pixel_command__58916 @ ados?t=1441363419357&request={"Placements":[{"A":22,"S":8277,"D":"adzerk24657264","ATA":[17,2221],"…:4
    root.azLoad @ ados.js:208
    (anonymous function) @ ados?t=1441363419357&request={"Placements":[{"A":22,"S":8277,"D":"adzerk24657264","ATA":[17,2221],"…:7
```

Seems it may be related to one or more of the adverts being displayed at the moment - it's being served from engine.adzerk.net.  Not critical, but annoying nonetheless.

Comment: We're tracking this issue, and Adzerk is currently working on a fix. (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263411/sometimes-a-syntaxerror-is-logged-to-console-while-viewing-questions-on-stack-ov)

Comment: In the meantime, adblock will do, as will not opening the JavaScript console :-D

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah it was mostly only annoying on questions that use stack snippets to console.log

Comment: "only annoying on questions that use stack snippets to console.log", oh, ok, now I understand. I was curious about how this could be annoying for anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for you patience on this - we have gotten this resolved on our side. We were incorrectly encoding some values in the impression data that was then throwing an error when we tried to parse it on the client side. It was tied to an new eventing system we have deployed on the client side, so it wasn't affecting any customers or data.