# When I load a Stack Overflow page I get "Your answer appears to be spam."

Tags: support

Something strange I have just noticed. When I arrive at a Stack Overflow page from Google I'm some how triggering the "Your answer appears to be spam" filter. I have not typed anything these appears to happen as the page is loading. Any suggestions on what this could be?

[image: "Your answer appears to be spam." screenshot]

Comment: Are you using a browser where you can view the Generated Source instead of regular View Source? (The Web Developer Toolbar lets you do this) If you can, do that and look for "wmd-preview" and see if there's any text or weird space characters in there.

Comment: `<div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-preview"></div>` this appears to be empty. However, the problem seems to be with my Lastpass extension. Problem goes away when I disable Lastpass.

Comment: Do you have any profiles saved in LastPass? Maybe it thinks the Answer section is some place it's supposed to be adding text to. (I have LastPass but I don't use it to login on SO.)

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305301/javascript-error-thrown-by-adzerk-script-in-many-page-loads  Perhaps that script error is causing LastPass issues that lead to this. Have you tried going to a different Stack Exchange site?